# Azure search filter with search.ismatch() not returning the correct results

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

We have a scenario where we use search.ismatch() to get the results having exactly the search word. For exact filtering we use "" around the word say for example search for the results which have the tag 'abc' will be retrieved using `search.ismatch('"abc"', 'tags')`.

We are seeing that for some of the simplified Chinese terms the query return results which do not have that exact tag in the tags list.

For example when search for '艾迪生' it returns results with documents tagged as '兰迪'. Is there is case why the search.ismatch() is not returning only the documents having that exact word match.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the index field you are searching for with a Chinese simplified language analyzer?  My thought is that the query language may not work properly for a non-English language unless the data is indexed into a field with the particular language analyzer.  Try it and see if that helps!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-language-analyzers

Comment: Hi, we have added language specific analyzers for example for simplified Chinese we have zh-Hans.microsoft text analyzer. But we are still seeing the issue where search.ismatch() is returning results even though there is no exact match.

Comment: This is what I experience too, ref. my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64485275/chinese-queries-result-in-unexpectly-high-recall. The results we get are equivalent of doing an OR-search for each Chinese character. Your search for 艾迪生 is interpreted as (艾 OR 迪 OR 生), which explains why you get a match for 兰迪'. 

This behavior is not as documented. I say it's a bug.