# Chinese queries result in unexpectly high recall

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, cjk

We experience unexpectedly high recall for Chinese queries. I have managed to reproduce a minimal use-case using a simple data model with only 2 properties.

**REPRODUCE**

1. Define a property DescriptionZhCn for Chinese product descriptions, using zh-Hans.microsoft analyzer
2. Populate two records with the following values in DescriptionZhCn

   Contoso 减振接杆

   Contoso 缩径接柄
3. Search using options searchMode=all, queryType=full, searchFields=DescriptionZhCn, api-version=2019-05-06 with the following values in the search parameter:

   减振接杆

   缩径接柄

**EXPECTED**

When searching for 减振接杆 I would expect only the record with description "Contoso 减振接杆". When searching for 缩径接柄 I would expect only the record "Contoso 缩径接柄".

**ACTUAL**

Searching either 减振接杆 or 缩径接柄 unexpectedly return both records. The only thing common character is the third character 接.

I have verified the output from the zh-Hans.microsoft analyzer and it splits both of the Chinese strings into 4 tokens. E.g.

```
减振接杆 => 减 振 接 杆
```

My query only matches one of the tokens. And I'm using searchMode=all. Why does my query match? Is this a bug? Any input [Yanoosh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162425/xyz), [Liam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4363193/liam-cavanagh-msft)?

Comment: For readability the Chinese characters in the two descriptions can be translated to ABCD and XYCW. The first string ABCD is tokenized to four distinct tokens A B C D. Similarly XYCW is tokenized to X Y C W.

Comment: It appears that this has to do with the search service itself. I now have four separate environments. In 3 of 4 environments I reproduce the problem. And the problem is that there is no difference between using searchMode=any or searchMode=all. In the 4th environment the searchMode=all option is interpreted correctly. 

As part of debugging I created a new search service from scratch. I then used the same Postman scripts to create an index, populate it with 3 minimal records. In Azure Search Explorer I then test with query string: 

search=缩径接柄&queryType=full&searchMode=all&$count=true