# How to stop zh-Hans.microsoft analyzer matching almost anything

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, cjk, analyzer, precision-recall

I can't get the Chinese linguistics in Azure Search working properly. It unexpectedly matches almost anything. For example, I have a minimal test case where a property using zh-Hans.microsoft analyzer contains the following:

**M / 6g**

This will unexpectedly match a query of **M1.6**. How is that possible? Even if my query would be tokenized into M1 and 6, it still should not match my content with tokens M and 6g?

I have tested 20 different analyzers. None of them result in a match, except when I use zh-Hans.microsoft.

**MINMAL INDEX**

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://{{SEARCH_SVC}}.{{DNS_SUFFIX}}/$metadata#indexes/$entity",
"@odata.etag": "\"0x8D8761DCBBCCD00\"",
"name": "products",
"defaultScoringProfile": null,
"fields": [
    {
        "name": "Id",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "facetable": false,
        "filterable": true,
        "key": true,
        "retrievable": true,
        "searchable": false,
        "sortable": true,
        "analyzer": null,
        "indexAnalyzer": null,
        "searchAnalyzer": null,
        "synonymMaps": [],
        "fields": []
    },
    {
        "name": "KeywordsZhCn",
        "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
        "facetable": true,
        "filterable": true,
        "retrievable": true,
        "searchable": true,
        "analyzer": "zh-Hans.microsoft",
        "indexAnalyzer": null,
        "searchAnalyzer": null,
        "fields": []
    }
],
"scoringProfiles": [],
"corsOptions": null,
"suggesters": [],
"analyzers": [],
"tokenizers": [],
"tokenFilters": [],
"charFilters": [],
"encryptionKey": null
```

}

**MINIMAL DOCUMENT**

{
"value": [
{
"@search.action": "mergeOrUpload",
"Id": "1",
"KeywordsZhCn": [
"M / 6g"
]
}
]
}

**EXAMPLE QUERY**
https://{{SEARCH_SVC}}.{{DNS_SUFFIX}}/indexes/products/docs?search=M1.6&$count=true&$select=Id,KeywordsZhCn&searchMode=all&queryType=full&api-version=2020-06-30-Preview&featuresMode=enabled&scoringStatistics=global

The featuresMode option is enabled, so I see where the unexpected match occurs.

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://<my-search-service>.search.windows.net/indexes('products')/$metadata#docs(*)",
"@odata.count": 1,
"value": [
    {
        "@search.score": 0.25811607,
        "@search.features": {
            "KeywordsZhCn": {
                "uniqueTokenMatches": 1.0,
                "similarityScore": 0.25811607,
                "termFrequency": 1.0
            }
        },
        "Id": "1",
        "KeywordsZhCn": [
            "M / 6g"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I have searched Stack Overflow for similar cases, but I can only find a post from myself from about a year ago where I had crazy recall issues with Chinese in Azure Search, ref. [Chinese queries result in unexpectly high recall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64485275/chinese-queries-result-in-unexpectly-high-recall)

OUTPUT FROM ANALYSIS
Updating my question with output from analysis.

Analyzing the content "M / 6g" with zh-Hans.microsoft analyzer produces these tokens:

```
"tokens": [
    {
        "token": "m",
        "startOffset": 0,
        "endOffset": 1,
        "position": 0
    },
    {
        "token": "6g",
        "startOffset": 4,
        "endOffset": 6,
        "position": 1
    }
]
```

The query M1.6 produces:

```
    "tokens": [
    {
        "token": "m",
        "startOffset": 0,
        "endOffset": 1,
        "position": 0
    },
    {
        "token": "1.6",
        "startOffset": 1,
        "endOffset": 4,
        "position": 1
    },
    {
        "token": "nn1d6",
        "startOffset": 1,
        "endOffset": 4,
        "position": 1
    }
]
```

Comment: Have you used the "Analyze Text" API to understand how each of your terms gets tokenized? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer - this should give you insights on where the match is happening.

Comment: Yes, I did. I updated my question with the output from the analyzer. The content produces tokens 

m 6g

The query produces 

m 1.6 nn1d6