# searchMode=all / searchMode=any return the same number of results on the th.microsoft analyzer?

Tags: azure, full-text-search, azure-cognitive-search

We create a field call "product_name" with the th.microsoft analyzer which breaks thai words in tokens.

However, when we call search api as queryType=simple, searchMode=all VS queryType=simple, searchMode=any, we get the same results.

It seems like the searchMode=all does not apply the logic that every tokens need to match in the results.

Any suggestion?

Comment: For more information, my issue is similar to this topic -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64485275/chinese-queries-result-in-unexpectly-high-recall

Answer (score 0):

You refer to one of my old posts where tokenization for certain languages like Chinese, Japanese and Korean would produce unexpectedly high recall.

I started a support case with Microsoft and they verified the buggy behavior. The root cause was an issue with the search service itself. I had 4 different search services and they behaved differently. In my case 3 of 4 environments reproduced the buggy behavior. If I created a new search service, it would work as expected. Older search services reproduced the buggy behavior.

It's easy to think that all search services created in Azure will be exactly the same. That's not the case. They will have subtle differences and versions behind the scenes, even if this is not exposed to you in the form of a version number.

Suggestion:

1. Create Postman scripts to accurately reproduce the steps from creating an index, indexing some test items and then testing queries with simple, any/all.
2. Create a new search service and compare the behavior

PS: Your original question would be better if you included specific examples of what you do, what results you get and what you expected.